# Is there a way to access "inner_hits" data from a script

Tags: elasticsearch

A response document from query with `"has_child"` clause with `inner_hits` has a structure similar to this:

```
 "hits": {
    ...
    "hits": [
      {
        METADATA
        "_source": {
            ...
        },
        "inner_hits": {
            INNER HITS DATA
        }
      },
      ....
```

Is there a way to access `inner_hits` content from a Groovy script ?

Answer (score 0):

No you cant :

see [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/access-to-inner-hits-from-painless-script-during-sorting/86926)

> It is not possible, in any scripting language (not just painless).
>   Inner hits are completely separate documents within lucene, but
>   scripts operate on a single document at a time.